# Novell search with VBScript for users

Tags: vbscript, novell

I have searched many places and found nothing of what I'm after..

I'm trying to run searches via vbs to find user details and modify.

I know it's easy enough to modify using the GUI... But in my job
I have to modify say 160 users from a spreadsheet and it would be GREAT
If I can do via a script ?

Our system uses active directory and Novell for now...

AD I can do want I need but Novell / console one I can't..

Comment: I found the following resources. What specifially are you connecting to and what functionality do you need? https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/novell.devsup.ldap_j/7x_snB2Go34
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=969032
https://forums.netiq.com/showthread.php?2877-VBScript-LDAP-find-user